# URL not found on localhost with WAMP

Tags: laravel, url, localhost, wamp

I've always been using xampp for localhost but recently I had problems with the ports and tried to run the localhost with Wamp Server. Everything looked fine but when I typed `localhost/bluedrive/drive/public` the browser showed `The requested URL /bluedrive/drive/public/auth/login was not found on this server.` I forgot to mention that i'm using Laravel 5. When I used XAMPP I didn't have such problems. Why there is one with WAMP SERVER?

Comment: try enabling rewrite_module in WAMP Server

Comment: @Junaid Yep, that worked for me. Actually what does this module do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable `mod_rewrite` in WAMP server.

> The [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module uses a rule-based rewriting engine, based on a PCRE regular-expression parser, to rewrite requested URLs on the fly.

so basically it sends the request to Laravel instead of finding folders with those names.